# Python: fsolve near asymptotic region

Tags: python, scipy, quad

For `E=0.46732451` and `t=1.07589765` I am trying to solve for the upper limit of the integral t= \int_{0}^{z} 1/sqrt(2*(0.46732451-z**2)), I plotted this function and it looks like this [image: z vs t].

Around `t=1` it kind of asymptotes.

I have the following code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def fg(z_up,t,E):
      def h(z,E):
           return 1/(np.sqrt(2*(E-z**2)))

      b, err = integrate.quad(h, 0, z_up,args=(E)) 
      return b-t 



x0 = 0.1
print fsolve(fg, x0, args=(1.07589765, 0.46732451))[0]
```

But this code just outputs the guess value, no matter what I put, so I am guessing it has something to do with the fact that the curve asymptotes there. I should note that this code works for other values of `t` which are away from the asymptotic region.

Can anyone help me resolve this?

Thanks

**EDIT** After playing around for a while, I solved the problem, but it's kind of a patchwork, it only works for similar problems not in general (or does it?)

I made the following changes: the maximum value that `z` can attain is `sqrt(0.46732451)`, so I set `x0=0.5*np.sqrt(0.46732451)` and set `factor` anywhere between `0.1` to `1`, and out pops the correct answer. I don't have an explanation for this, perhaps someone who is an expert in this matter can help?

Comment: fsolve will occasionally try values relatively far away from your starting point. This can cause the argument for sqrt to become negative. You should check for the argument first, and return a special value the indicates "don't try here" to fsolve if the argument is smaller than 0 (any reasonably large value may work).

Comment: Verify that the argument is actually `2 * (E - z**2)`, and not for example `2 * (E - z)**2`.

Comment: No the argument is 2 * (E - z**2)

Comment: Have you tried providing a value for [`factor`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html)? The docs describe it as "a parameter determining the initial step bound."

Comment: Also, it would be a lot easier to help if you provide code that runs. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes, I did try putting in numbers between factor=0.1 to 100, but nothing worked.

Comment: typos and bugs fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`bisect`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.bisect.html#scipy.optimize.bisect) instead, as it handles `nan` without problems:

```
print bisect(fg, 0.4, 0.7, args=(1.07589765, 0.46732451))
```

Here 0.4 and 0.7 are taken as an example but you can generalize this for almost any diverging integral by using `0` and let's say `1e12` as the limits.

However, I'm not sure I understand what you really want to do... if you want to find the limit at which the integral diverges, cf. your

> I am trying to solve for the upper limit of the integral

then it's simply for `z_up -> \sqrt{E} \approx 0,683611374`...
So to find the (approximate) numerical value of the integral you just have to decrease `z_up` from that value until `quad` stops giving a `nan`...

Comment: I don't see why my approach is not the right approach. Your approach is another way of solving the problem. Also, it's not superior to mine, since you have to include the bounds `0.4` and `0.7`, to determine them you do need to know that `zmax` is at `0.683611374`. I want to find the upper limit of the integral given the value of the integral is `1.07589765`, which occurs at a point very close to the point at which the integral diverges, but not at that point.

Comment: It's just that `fsolve` does not deal well with `nan` whereas `bisect` does.
And to find the numerical value of the integral, you should really just decrease `z_up` from `\sqrt{E}` as stated in my answer: that will avoid using a value for `t` when it's actually the variable you're looking for

Comment: Not really, my problem is I have a list of `t` (the value of the integral) and `E` and I want to find the corresponding `z` which is the upper limit of the integral. True, but by mentioning a better `x0` and the `factor=0.1-1` you can avoid actually hitting `NaN`

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry, I really don't get it: the upper value of the integral is `\sqrt{E}`...
But if you mean the value of `z` for which the integral reaches a specific value of `t`, then my solution will always work since you just have to provide `0` and let's say `1.1*E` as boundaries for `bisect` and you always have `E`...

Comment: I think you meant `1.1*sqrt(E)`, yes I agree, and so will my method. Both methods work.

Comment: Well, thank you for your appreciation. Then it could be a good idea to accept an answer to show people than this problem has been solve. You can answer you own question if my answer doesn't suit you.